# I get an "invalid property name" error while running my code in pycharm. i have a simple python "main.py" file and a kivy "MyQuiz.kv" file

Tags: python, kivy

OK, so i'm trying to make an app using python and kivy.From tutorials and from search on google i've seen people using kivy language to simplify their code but when i try to create a kv file for my program i get an "Invalid property name" ERROR and i dont know what to do.I did everything the guy on the tutorial did and followd every instruction on google but still i get this error.Did anyone had the same problem before and how did you solve it? Thanks in advance!
**This is my python file:**

```
           import kivy
           #kivy.require('1.0.6') # replace with your current kivy version !
           from kivy.app import App
           from kivy.uix.label import Label
           from kivy.uix.button import Button
           from kivy.uix.scatter import Scatter
           from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
           from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
           from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
           from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager,Screen
           from kivy.lang import Builder
           from kivy.properties import NumericProperty

           class QuizWidget(BoxLayout):
                  pass

           class MyQuizApp(App):

                  def build(self):
                      return QuizWidget()

           if __name__ == '__main__':
                   MyQuizApp().run()
```

**This is my kivy file:**

```
<QuizWidget>:
orientation = 'vertical'
TextInput:
    id: Start_text
    font_size: 100
    size_hint_y: None
    height: 200
    text: 'Wellcome to my quiz.Press START to continue'
    Button:
        text:'START'
        font_size: 150
```

Answer (score 0):

```
orientation = 'vertical'
```

This should be `orientation: 'vertical'`. Kivy is trying to parse the whole thing as a property name since you didn't have a :. The error should probably point to this line, but you didn't give enough info to check.